# read webConfigurationManager.AppSettings from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, configuration, webforms

I have an asp.net page where I need to read some appSetting value from web.config. After googling, I found that I can use this code:

```
using System.Web.Configuration;

WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["configFile"]
```

but after I insert the line using System.Web.Configuration by typing in this at my aspx page

```
<%@ Using System.Web.Configuration; %>
```

I got this error: ASP.net runtime error. Only content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content control. So how can I read the system web configuration file from my asp page if it doesn't allow me to import System.Web.Configuration?

Comment: is this mvc or webforms?

Comment: @DaveBecker it's a web app. Actually I'm trying to change the href in <a href="Account/ForgotPassword.aspx">Forgot my password</a> to something from the web.config

Comment: okay, I know how to do that but I need to know if it is a mvc web app (then the answer is model based) or webforms web app (where there will be code behind).

Comment: @DaveBecker it's a webforms web app because there's a code behind

Comment: okay cool. So, just add the `using System.Web.Configuation` to your code behind then create a function in the code behind to return the setting from `web.config` and call it from your page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do the trick (I've never used `WebConfigutationManager` but this works for me).

**Code Behind**

```
using System.Configuration

protected string GetForgottenUrl()
{
  return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeKey"];
}
```

**Aspx Page**

```
<a href='<%= GetForgottenUrl()%>'>Forgot Password</a>
```

**Web.Config**

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
     <add key="SomeKey" value="SomePage.aspx" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT:**: You may need to add a reference to `System.Configuration`